# XCode 8 Segmentation fault 11

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Since updating my app to swift3 when i try to build the app it shows the following error:
"command failed due to signal : segmentation fault: 11 ".

The issue is with two .swift files in my project.
I did a copy-paste of the exact code in each file to a playground project. While it will temporarily show an "Internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited", the code will compile..

I have already deleted the derived data, i have cleaned the pods from the projects and installed them again.

Any ideas as to why is this happening and what would a possible fix be?

Answer (score 2):

This is often caused by an incorrect type in a dictionary, incorrect cast or something else relatively simple.

Post your code so that we can see.